# Tracking transfers of ERC-721 tokens from another contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, erc-721

I have an ERC-721 token manager contract and an ERC-721 token contract. The manager contract is responsible for creating new ERC-721 contracts and minting new tokens within those contracts, as well as keeping track of wallets that have tokens and which tokens they own. Just realized a potentially fatal flaw - since I am keeping track of wallets that own tokens *IF* a token is traded outside of my platform the token manager contract will be out of sync. Anyone have any thoughts or ideas about how I can make this work, or a better solution to track which wallets have tokens in which ERC-721 contracts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your token contract needs to directly notify the token manager contract whenever a token is transferred by a third party.

Store the address of the token manager contract in the token contract

```
address private token_manager_address = 0xabcd;
```

and in your `transferFrom` and `safeTransferFrom` functions, have a check which says

```
if(msg.sender != token_manager_address){
    //do something to notify the token manager contract
}
```